# Circuit Design Confusion

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, circuit-design

I am trying to design an AC-DC converter using the [SM7035P](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Shenzhen-Sunmoon-Micro-SM7035P_C136191.pdf)

The pinout is
[image]

However I am confused with the pins 7,8 as in the reference design they don't connect to ground directly -

[image]
(Where DC+ is considered GND)

Is this an error in the reference design or am I reading it wrong? Please help.

Comment: Everything is ok, the GND pins are connected to the internal MOSFET Source terminal.

Comment: They call it "chip ground" not "ground " on page 2.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany They should have called it "Source" or maybe even Vss. GND just confuses people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's intentional, this is a known design for an [off-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_line_regulator) switcher with buck topology.

The internal supply of the chip charges the capacitor on the VDD pin with the voltage differential between the drain and GND (source) pin when the internal MOSFET switch is off. The capacitor will then continue to power the circuit long enough when the MOSFET is switched on and the voltage differential is very low.

Similar parts are for example the [UCC28880](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc28880.pdf) or the [LNK30X](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/lnk302_304-306.pdf) family, with more details about the different topologies in English.